# order_by doesn't work with __in

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am implementing a playlist system in my webapp for audio, I'm using DRF for the API and I've been trying to sort playlist items by index.

```
playlist = self.get_playlist()

qs = playlist.items.order_by('index')
qs = Track.objects.filter(playlist_items__in=qs)
```

However this does not work, as soon as the `__in` query is used, it's ordering by track `pk`, not the `index` of a playlist item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach doesn't make sense. `order_by` is applied on the result queryset on `Track`, not on conditions. You should do

`Track.objects.filter(playlist_items__in=qs).order_by('playlist_items__index')`

In details, `__in` statement is translated into `IN` statement in sql, like

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

But sql uses `ORDER BY` statement to sort the result, like:

```
SELECT column_name, column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;
```

Comment: Wait.. this doesn't make sense to me. How does it know which playlist_items it should order by when a track can have multiple playlist_items from different playlists?